# huge printf float/double difference in integer digits on windows/linux

Tags: c, windows, gcc, floating-point, printf

```
#include <float.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  printf("[0] %f\n", FLT_MAX); 
  printf("[1] %lf\n", FLT_MAX); 
  printf("[2] %Lf\n", FLT_MAX); // gcc warning: expects argument of type     ‘long double’ 
  printf("[3] %f\n", DBL_MAX); 
  printf("[4] %lf\n", DBL_MAX); 
  printf("[5] %Lf\n", DBL_MAX); // gcc warning: expects argument of type     ‘long double’ 

  //using C++ und std::numeric_limits<float/double>::max() gives same     results

  return 0; 
}
```

Linux:
x64 
lsb_release -d prints "Description: Ubuntu 15.04" 
gcc --version prints "gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2" 
ldd --version prints "ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.21-0ubuntu4) 2.21"

```
[0] 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 
[1] 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 
[2] --> warning-line disabled 
[3] 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000 
[4] 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000 
[5] --> warning-line disabled
```

Windows 7 x64:
VS2010 (latest Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel) Debug/Win32

```
[0] 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000000 
[1] 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000000 
[2] 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000000
[3] 179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 
[4] 179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 
[5] 179769313486231570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

difference on FLT_MAX 
VS2010:   340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000000 
GCC4.9.2: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000

is 1.8829581651548307456e+20 (not that small) - and getting much bigger using doubles

**UPDATE: actual question**

Is there a way (with only a small change of the code) to get the same result on Linux and Windows (and others) or do I need to use the very same implementation on all systems? I'm afraid of having my own implementation for my Windows/Linux/Linux-ARM/VxWorks/Solaris platforms.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: So there are platform differences. The C standard allows for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` function is implemented differently on these platforms.

Look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%lf\n", ((double)1e100)/3);
    return 0;
}
```

This program compiled with VC++ gives:

```
3333333333333333200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

while the same program compiled with g++ gives:

```
3333333333333333224453896013722304246165110619355184909726539264904319486405759542029132894851563520.000000
```

Comment: sorry for beeing unclear: it is clear to me that the result is implementation depended - but i've never though that the integer part of the float could be "interepreted" that wrong by different impls

Comment: @llm: If that's not what you wanted, then maybe you should ask an actual question instead of just stating facts.

Comment: @llm You are dealing with floating point numbers so only *relative error* is important there, the internal representation is unable to support fixed absolute error.

Comment: actual question: is there a way (small change) to get the same result on linux/windows (and others) or do i need to use the very same implementation on both(all) systems - im afraid of having my own implementation for my win/linux/linux-arm/vxworks/solaris platforms

Comment: @llm You have to respect the floating point precision and you should not rely on digits that are beyond that. In other words: Write your program in a way that's insensitive to such differences.

Comment: @dlask: Even if you respect the precision, it might be desirable (for example for improved UX) to get one version or the other on *all* platforms. I think that's a valid concern.

Comment: @llm: Please edit your question to include the "actual question" you just stated here.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the platforms is in how the numbers are printed, not in the numbers themselves.

You seem to misunderstand how floating-point numbers work. Their accuracy is relative to their magnitude. The magnitude is repesented by the number's exponent, the value by its mantissa. The size of the mantissa is fixed, for `float` it is 23 bits plus one implicit bit. Converted to decimal, this means that you can represent about seven significant decimal digits accurately.

`FLT_MAX` is about 3.40282346639e+38. The next smaller number that can be represented as a `float` is about 3.40282326356e+38. That's a difference of 2.02824096037e+31 or ten orders of magnitude larger than your perceived error.

Even if the apparent difference between the numbers seems to be huge, both printed values are much closer to `FLT_MAX` than to any other single-precision floating-point number and re-converting the textual representation to ´float`should yield`FLT_MAX`.

In short: Both implementations of `printf` are valid.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way (with only a small change of the code) to get the same result on Linux and Windows?

Yes - mostly.

1. Use `gcc` on Windows.  By "Windows", certainly OP is referring to a Visual Stdio compiler or related product.  `gcc` is available on Windows, Linux, and many other platforms and with more consistent results than OP's examples.  It is really a *compiler* issue and not an *OS* one.
2. Use base-2/16 output.

   ```
   printf("%a\n", FLT_MAX);
   // 0x1.fffffep+127  gcc 4.9.2
   // 0x1.fffffep+127  VS 2010
   ```
3. Use `"%.e"` with limited precision.  The C spec only specifies a *minimum* precision of 6 digits for `float` and 10 for `double`, else use `FLT_DIG/DBL_DIG`.

To fix 2/3 digit exponent, see [How to control the number of exponent digits ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31331723/2410359) and [visual studio `_set_output_format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0fatw238(v=vs.140).aspx)
Note that the precision field in `"%.*e"` is the number of digits after the lead digits, thus code uses `-1`.

```
    printf("%.*e\n", FLT_DIG - 1, FLT_MAX);
    // 3.40282e+38     gcc 4.9.2
    // 3.40282e+038    VS 2010
```

3. Use `"%.e"` with more, but not excessive, precision.  `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG/DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is the number of digits to print to read the value back and end up with the same `float` value.  Printing with more digits leads to OP's problem.  Consider `double`: Notice VS printed in OP's post to 17 correctly rounded significant digits.  If defined in VS, `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` would be 17 there.  VS prints to 17 digits to preserve "round-tripping" numbers.   By directing `gcc` to print to 17 significant digits, we get the same result.

   ```
   #ifdef FLT_DECIMAL_DIG
     //  FLT_DECIMAL_DIG/DBL_DECIMAL_DIG typically not available in VS
     #define OP_FLT_Digs (FLT_DECIMAL_DIG)
     #define OP_DLB_Digs (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG)
   #else  
     #define OP_FLT_Digs (FLT_DIG + 3)
     #define OP_DBL_Digs (DBL_DIG + 2)
   #endif
   printf("%.*e\n", OP_FLT_Digs - 1, FLT_MAX);
   // 3.40282347e+38     gcc 4.9.2
   // 3.40282347e+038    VS 2010
   ```
4. More on `"%.e"`.  There is value in not printing to more than `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG/DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits due to corner cases when scanning back the number will result in the *next* FP number.  Essentially a double rounding issue - somewhat deep for this post - so no details.
5. Of course all this is moot if the various systems are using vastly different FP formats which is quite probable with `long double`.  Exact FP consistency is difficult, but the above will certainly help minimize differences.

Comment: How do you figure the C standard specifies “a *minimum* precision”? C 1999 7.19.6.1 8 says, for `e`, “… the number of digits after it [the decimal point] is equal to the precision; if the precision is missing, it is taken as 6;…” Draft N1570 for 2011 says the same thing, and 2018 official says the same thing.