# How to control the number of exponent digits after 'e' in C printf %e?

Tags: c, printf

I want to control the number of exponent digits after 'e' in C `printf %e`?

For example, C `printf("%e")` result `2.35e+03`, but I want `2.35e+003`, I need 3 digits of exponent, how do I use `printf`?

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double x=34523423.52342353;
    printf("%.3g\n%.3e",x,x);
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**
http://codepad.org/dSLzQIrn

```
3.45e+07
3.452e+07
```

I want

```
3.45e+007
3.452e+007
```

But interestingly, I got the right results in Windows with MinGW.

Comment: The "Windows" behavior is non-conforming and VS2015 will use at least 2 exponents digits by default (see [*exponent formatting*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531344%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)).

Comment: @cremno With what is "Windows" non-conforming  concerning  exponent width? Other than conforming or not to OP's goal?

Comment: @cremno I see  "...The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent. ..."  §7.21.6.1

Comment: @chux: Yes, that's the reason why it isn't conforming to C99/C11. The rationale also contains: “For `%e`, C99 clarifies that small exponents contain at least 2 digits, but no more than are necessary to represent the value.  Prior to C99, it was not clear that an arbitrary number of leading zeros were not allowed.”

Comment: @cremno Too bad, that at the time of C99 a control mechanism was not defined that would address this.  IMO, a minimum of 2 is an odd choice - likely prior art.  At _least_, the spec should define a constant of the maximum width expected.  This would aid in right-sizing `"%e"` buffers.  Else code needs something like  `ilog10(DBL_MAX_10_EXP)+1`.  Thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "...The exponent always contains at least two digits, and only as many more digits as necessary to represent the exponent. ..."  C11dr §7.21.6.1 8

So `3.45e+07` is compliant (what OP does not want) and `3.45e+007` is not compliant (what OP wants).

As C does not provide a standard way for code to alter the number of exponent digits, code is left to fend for itself.

Various compilers support some control.

[visual studio `_set_output_format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/set-output-format)

For fun, following is DIY code

```
  double x = 34523423.52342353;
  //                    - 1 . xxx e - EEEE \0
  #define ExpectedSize (1+1+1 +3 +1+1+ 4 + 1)
  char buf[ExpectedSize + 10];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.3e", x);
  char *e = strchr(buf, 'e');  // lucky 'e' not in "Infinity" nor "NaN"
  if (e) {
    e++;
    int expo = atoi(e);
    snprintf(e, sizeof buf - (e - buf), "%05d", expo);  // 5 more illustrative than 3
  }
  puts(buf);

  3.452e00007
```

Also see [c++ how to get "one digit exponent" with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773133/c-how-to-get-one-digit-exponent-with-printf)

Comment: Thanks, I finally use `_set_output_format` to get the same result.

Comment: First, Nice answer!  Regarding the question _[here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37187540/645128)_,  this answer would also a good fit.  I am just not sure how it works.  `e` in `snprintf` is the target buffer, but `buf` is modified with the result.  How?

Comment: @ryyker `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.3e", x);` forms the exponential string version of `x`.  So `buf` should have an `'e'` in it right before the exponential digits.  Then code reads from `buf` just after `'e'` to get the exponent.  Then it it prints it _back_ to `buf` with `snprintf(e, sizeof buf ...`, this time with the desired formatting.  In this case `"%05d"`, in [that case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37187540/645128), use `"%d"`.

Comment: This answer has convinced me to just use search and replace to get to what I need... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`printf` Format tags prototype:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

> The **precision**
>
> > ... This gives ... the number of digits to appear after
> >     the **radix** character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions ... .

You are using the conversion and the precision specifier correctly, the difference is with the implementations of the C library function and the environments on the differing systems. The `precision` specifies the number of digits after the `'.'` (dot, period, etc..). It does not set the number of characters that represent the exponentiation. The facts that it provides `3 digits` on windows is just the way windows specifies the format, not the way the C standard library specifies that `printf` will work.

It would take comparing how the source implementations differ to see what is relied on for that piece of the format string. (it will probably boil down to some obscure difference in the way the windows v. linux/unix environments/locale/etc. are defined or specified)

Comment: oh I see, bad c/c++, it's not truly cross platform. Is it due to the difference of os or compilers? is there any compiler get the same result with win mingw?

Comment: Not "bad C++", but "bad Microsoft". It´s cleary specified what `%e` etc. should do, but MS gives a sh* (there are so many things like that in VS that it´s just sad)

Comment: Well, this is where that nasty thing quasi-related to **implementation defined** comes into play. Since the number of digits in the exponentiation isn't specified as part of the standard, different compilers are free to implement that part however they like. It may even be that the mingw implementation is the **exact same** as the normal unix/linux glibc implementation, but the part of the OS environment relied upon in forming that part is different between windows/mingw/linux/etc... It's a tough one. That's why  you need to figure out what is actually used in the final output. **fun...**

Comment: So, I can't get the exact same result between Windows and Linux?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: This is not implementation-defined at all. ISO C (at least C99 and C11 and I believe also C89) specify the exact formatting for floating point formats, and the MS library is wrong.

Comment: I stand corrected. I looked at the man page and skimmed the standard but must have missed the digit specification for the exponentiation. Old eyes....

Answer (score -3):

```
char *nexp(double x, int p, int n) // Number with p digits of precision, n digits of exponent.
{
 const int NN=12;
 static char s[NN][256];//(fvca)
 static int i=-1;
 int j,e;

 i=(++i)%NN; // Index of what s is to be used...
 sprintf(s[i],"%.*lE", p,x); // Number...
 for(j=0; s[i][j]; j++) if(s[i][j]=='E') break; // Find the 'E'...
 if(s[i][j]=='E') // Found!
  {
   e= atoi(s[i]+j+1);
   sprintf(s[i]+j+1, "%+0*d", n+1,e);
   return s[i];
  }
 else return "***";
}


// Best Regards, GGa
// G_G
```

Comment: `i=(++i)%NN;` - Please do not write code like this (i.e. increments inside an expression). Getting into this habit will lead to problems in the future.

Comment: OK, changed to:    ++i%=NN;

Comment: Also using `static` is a bad idea - as it prevents the code from being used in MT environments

Comment: The behavior of `i=(++i)%NN;` is not defined by the C standard: “If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined” (C 2018 6.5 2).