# Is it possible to set the number of digits wanted in the exponent in floating point representation in C, printf?

Tags: c, printf, exponent

Is it possible to set this, for example to not have 2.4e+002 but 2.4e2? I really have been searching for this hard, and know how to set with precision the number preceding "e" but the exponent just isn't clear as to what I can do with.No where that I have searched, have I found how to specify this expoenent. I would like to use a integer to specify the number of characters to be presented after "e" and somehow to not include "+" when it is positive, but ofcourse "-" to be included when the exponent is negative.

This is what I want the floating value to be represented in accordance to the following examples:

```
 134.5 ......  1.345e2
 -21.5 ...... -2.1e1
 -0.005...... 5e-3
```

By the way, the numbers on the left side of these examples are presented as strings, so I can use that quite easily to bound the number of needed characters left of "e".
Could this at all be done using the library functions in C, or should I just right the code myself, which might take some time. Right now, doing printf("%e",fl) will yield too many zeros and un-needed plus sign in the exponent if need be. Anyway to get rid of this in say, less than 20 lines of code using library functions?

Comment: Does this relate to a presentation issue or a calculation issue?

Comment: Post your code so that we can help.

Comment: @trojanfoe - "number of characters to be _presented_ after "e""

Comment: `The exponent always contains at least two digits; if the value is zero, the exponent is 00.` - this is what the doc says, so if you want that you will  have to write your own print functions.

Comment: Yes, all that you have asked for is possible using library functions.    There are so many ways, that no definitive answer is possible.

Comment: Some libraries provide control (e.g. Visual Studio).  There is no _standard_ method.

Comment: The `iostream` is about a different language library.