# How to display 2.33e+002 in C in VS2015?

Tags: c, printf, number-formatting

From *C Primer Plus, the 6th edition* Chapter 4, Review Questions
[image]

I'm working on the last question, I assumed the answer is `%12.2e`, but it display on the screen like '2.33e+02', one '0' missing.

I wonder if there is a way to change the display mode of exponent form floating-point number.

I'm using VS2015.

Comment: Well, [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) says "The exponent contains at least two digits, more digits are used **only if necessary**" for the `e` notation (emphasis mine). Not sure what more to say.

Comment: AFAICT, 2 digits of exponent are guaranteed; 3 digits are only used when necessary. IOW, you'd have to post-process what the system provides (using `snprintf()` or similar to format to a string and then editing the string).

Comment: if you're on MSVC then it can be set by `_set_output_format`

Comment: OOPs since VS2015 it was removed and it can only set to 2 digits https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fatw238(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @JoeDF unfortunately, the answer in appendix is exactly what I assumed, so I have to find it out here. Thank you all the same :)

Comment: [How to control the number of exponent digits after 'e' in C printf %e?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31331723/995714)