# Format changes in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, printf

The sample program. simply print converted value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char buffer[256] = "";
    sprintf_s(buffer, "%.2e", -20.12345);
    cout << buffer << endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

Run same program in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2015.

They are showing different output.

Visual Studio 2010 output:

```
-2.01e+001
```

Visual Studio 2015 output:

```
-2.01e+01
```

why is it showing different output?
anybody can explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scientific notation in the form of `<m>E<n>` means m*10<sup>n</sup>, where both `m` and `n` can be positive or negative. This means that `-2.01e+001` and `-2.01e+01` are in fact the same number (-2.01*10<sup>1</sup>). However, when using `e` format specifier, you can actually output numbers with a really big or really small *e* values, for example you can output `2e150`. The 3-digit exponent is used to pad the output strings and make them more uniform (consider `2e99, 2e101` vs `2e099, 2e101`).

It is also possible to use [_set_output_format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fatw238(v=vs.80).aspx) function to change the amount of digits that will be shown. It's worth noting that on that documentation page it is also stated that

> By default, the output of floating point numbers by functions such as printf, wprintf, and related functions in the Visual C++ Standard C library prints three digits for the exponent, even if three digits are not required to represent the value of the exponent. Zeroes are used to pad the value to three digits.

Comment: can I remove extra padded zero? if yes then how? I have converted my project from VS 2010 to VS 2015. VS 2015 give me compile error like that " Failure in Format: Expected -2.01e+01 but was -2.01e+001 "

Comment: @VijayKumbhani, please read the answer thoroughly, I've already mentioned that: `It is also possible to use _set_output_format function to change the amount of digits that will be shown.`

Comment: _set_output_format actually does not exist anymore, starting from VS2015

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Chux in [How to control the number of exponent digits after 'e' in C printf %e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331723/how-to-control-the-number-of-exponent-digits-after-e-in-c-printf-e), the compliant behavior is to use two digits for the exponent unless more are needed.  Prior to VS-2015, VS was non-compliant.  Apparently _set_output_format was provided to allow compliant behavior.

Since _set_output_format was removed in VS-2015 - and the behavior was changed to two digit exponents - one must assume that VS is attempting to be more compliant.

I found this because I need the compliant behavior in my application :-(

Comment: I need the non compliant behavior to be compatible with an older non compliant format. Now that MS decided to be compliant and removed _set_output_format it has become impossible (without writing your own fprint variants or going back to older Visual Studio versions). Microsoft at it's best!